# Close popup after receiving access token for oauth2 in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oauth-2.0, popup

I am trying to connect to an oauth2 flow of my city, I want the user to be able to get a popup where he can log in and then after we receive an access token the popup should close and the main window should be reloaded (so i can use the token).

I am having issues with figuring out how to close the popup after the oauth2 flow is done...
this is my code so far:

```
<button id="customBtnAprofielLogin" type="button" class="btn btn-social">
    <span class="fa"></span>
    <span><?=lang("antwerpen_alogin")?></span>
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var signinWin;
    $('#customBtnAprofielLogin').click(function () {
        //var pos = screenCenterPos(800, 500);
        signinWin = window.open("https://api-oauth2.city.be/v1/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost/codeigniter/login/city/aProfielCallback&lng=nl&scope=username+name+avatar+email+phone&service=city-aprofiel-v1&response_type=code", "SignIn", "width=972,height=660,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");
        setTimeout(CheckLoginStatus, 2000);
        signinWin.focus();
        return false;
    });

    function CheckLoginStatus() {
        if (signinWin.closed) {
            alert("yeey its closed");
        } else setTimeout(CheckLoginStatus, 1000);
        console.log(signinWin.document);
        if (signinWin.location.href) {
            console.log("URL CHANGED");
        }
    }
</script>
```

By this code i can see that the URL changed works as soon as I get an access token, however, the console inspector is full of errors indicating it is a cross origin error (which is logical). However, I dont think this is the correct way to go seeing all the errors popup until the popup has done reloading.

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost"
>   from accessing a cross-origin frame.